# How to Detach a Behavior from an UIElement in Code Behind for Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0, uielement

In Silverlight 3.0 I have added a custom behavior to some `UIElement` in Code Behind.

I wanted to remove the Behavior later in runtime.

What is the C# syntax to Detach an already added Behavior from an `UIElement`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am guessing you are talking about a behavior deriving from the `Behavior<T>` class in the Blend SDK...

Do you still have a reference to the behavior from when you attached it?

```
MyCustomBehavior myBehavior = new MyCustomBehavior();
myBehavior.Attach(myElement);
...
myBehavior.Detach();
```

**EDIT**

If you no longer have a reference to the instance of the behavior when you want to detach it you can do something like this to detach all behaviors on a DependencyObject:

```
foreach (var behavior in Interaction.GetBehaviors(myElement))
{
    behavior.Detach();
}
```

Comment: After Detach(), Attach() cannot re-attach or restore the behavior to the dependency object. solution?